# wordpress not accessing wp-admin because of htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Im new to wordpress i changed my site path from:

```
localhost/site/
```

to:

```
localhost/site/home/
```

now i cant access the files and wp-admin to undo that.Which file should i modify to fix my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the database you can update the wp_options table amending the rows where the option_names are "siteurl" and "home".

If you can't amend those then you can add these to your wp-config file (setting the relevant paths):

define('WP_HOME','http://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yourdomain.com');

Comment: it works for home directory but it didn't work for site/wp-admin/

Comment: The wp-admin url should now be localhost/site/home/wp-admin if you've changed the two settings described above.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some quick tips:

1. Make sure new path is duly updated in in your `wp-admin -> settings`
2. Make sure new path is reflected as RewriteBase in `$WP_HOME/.htaccess`
3. Make sure new path is reflected as RewriteBase in `$WP_HOME/admin/.htaccess`
4. Go through each & every step listed here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: hmm .htaccess file is good the problem is how to access wp-admin